# Laravel show orders with items, atributes and product

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to show orders from a database in Laravel. I have a bit of a problem because it isn't working.

What I want to do:

Show orders per user (on the user profile) with order data, item data, product data, and attribute data.

Here is the ERD I created:
[image: ERD]

Currently, I made this code, it's not working as it shows 1 order only and the wrong attributes.

```
 $products = Order::where('userid', $userId)->get();

    foreach ($products as $product) {

        $items = Item::where('order_id', $product->id)->get();

        foreach ($items as $item) {

            $productname = Product::where('id', $item->product_id)->get();

            foreach ($items as $attribute) {

                $attribute = Atribute::where('item_id', $attribute->id)->get();

            }

        }

    }

    return view('profile', compact('items', 'productname', 'attribute', 'user'));
}
```

How can I show orders from a user on their profile? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are fetching orders or products from `Order` model?

Comment: @DrakulaPredator according to the diagram: Orders are being fetched.

Comment: @DrakulaPredator Yes but the models are empty, it's a straight connection with the table "order"

Comment: You should take a look at relationships in Laravel. It will save you a lot of unnecessary iterations and expensive queries: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You were nesting your foreaches a little bit too much.

I removed the foreach here, and just changed `$attribute->id` to `$item->id`.

```
foreach ($items as $attribute) {
    $attribute = Atribute::where('item_id', $attribute->id)->get();
}
```

Complete code:

```
$products = Order::where('userid', $userId)->get();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $items = Item::where('order_id', $product->id)->get();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $productname = Product::where('id', $item->product_id)->get();

        $attribute = Atribute::where('item_id', $item->id)->get();
    }
}

return view('profile', compact('items', 'productname', 'attribute', 'user'));
```

You should also have a look at Laravel Relationships to make this whole process easier for you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thank you, but this only shows one order, how can I show all orders that a user posted

Comment: If you have multiple rows where the `$userId` matches with the `userid` column, then the above code should output all rows which contain it.